# React-Native Unittest a remove on keyboardListener

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I am using Jest to unittest my react native application. I have a question
about a certain test. When I create a certain component I add a listener to the keyboard
when the component unMounts I remove the listener.

```
this.keyboardDidShowSub.remove();
```

this is how I add the listener:

```
this.keyboardDidShowSub = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this.handleKeyboardDidShow);
```

What should I expect to happen in my unittest. So what should happen to this.keyboardDidShowSub
when I call the remove() function.

thx a lot!

Comment: how do you initialize `this.keyboardDidShowSub`? what's inside?

Comment: @skyboyer added it to the question